# Show $x^x+y^y=z^z+t^t$ has no solution in integers for distinct $x,y,z,t$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Prove that there does not exist pairwise distinct positive integers $x,y,x,t$ such that $$x^x+y^y=z^z+t^t\;.$$

I was trying to find some inequalities by assuming a solution does exist but cant get anywhere.

Comment: From which contest is this? (And a side-note: Somehow it seems more appropriate to use $w$ rather than $t$, but that's probably just mild OCD on my part!)

Comment: Its from New Zealand.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x,y,z,t$ be pairwise distinct positive integers. Without loss of generality assume that $t$ is greater than $x,y,z$. Then $t>2$ and $(t-1)^{t-1}$ is not smaller than both $x^x, y^y$. Therefore
$$z^z + t^t > t^t > t \cdot (t-1)^{t-1} > 2(t-1)^{t-1} \ge x^x + y^y$$
so $x^x+y^y\neq z^z+t^t$.

Comment: How is $t.t^{t-1}>2t^t$?

Comment: Yes doesnt it implies $t<0$.

Comment: I meant $2(t-1)^{t-1}$. I'll correct it in a sec. Thanks.

Comment: Well nice solution, just an alternative $t.t^{t-1}>2t^{t-1}$ and $t-1\ge x$ and $t>x$, which gives $2t^{t-1}\ge x^x+y^y$.